# Convertir un array de objetos en objeto indexado de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, angular, object

Tengo el siguiente array :

```
const connections = [{fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_0", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_0"},
                     {fromBox: 0, fromConnector: "port_1", toBox: 1, toConnector: "port_1"},
                     {fromBox: 1, fromConnector: "port_0", toBox: 4, toConnector: "port_0"}
                    ]
```

y necesito pasarlo a un objeto con indices como :

```
"connections": {
    "0": {
      "fromBox": "0",
      "fromConnector": "port_0",
      "toBox": "1",
      "toConnector": "port_0",
    },
    "1": {
      "fromBox": "0",
      "fromConnector": "port_1",
      "toBox": "1",
      "toConnector": "port_1"
    },
    "2": {
      "fromBox": "1",
      "fromConnector": "port_0",
      "toBox": "4",
      "toConnector": "port_0"
    }
  }
```

He encontrado una solucion sencilla que sería el Object.assign:

```
const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...connections );
```

Este metodo me genera un objeto pero no se como asignarles un indice e introducir el string "connections" como key del objeto.

Si alguien se le ocurre alguna solucion u orientacion sera bien recibida.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Por favor mira el array `connections` ya que me da ami que no es valido o al menos el que has publicado.

Comment: @EugeniBejan corregido, era de un error que arrastraba en una funcion anterior y creaba un index erroneo

Comment: Has probado con `let ob =  {connections: Object.assign({}, connections)}` ? Obtienes el resultado que muestras

Comment: @EugeniBejan perfecto... solo me faltaba introducir el "connections" tras corregir el anterior error... muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Guay, lo dejo como respuesta por si alguien en un futuro se encuentra con el mismo problema.

Comment: genial @EugeniBejan asi la marco como seleccionada y correcta. muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más sencilla es guardar el resultado de `Object.assign` en una clave de un nuevo objeto.

Ejemplo:

```js
const connections = [{
        fromBox: 0,
        fromConnector: "port_0",
        toBox: 1,
        toConnector: "port_0"
    },
    {
        fromBox: 0,
        fromConnector: "port_1",
        toBox: 1,
        toConnector: "port_1"
    },
    {
        fromBox: 1,
        fromConnector: "port_0",
        toBox: 4,
        toConnector: "port_0"
    },
]


//Crear un nuevo objeto
let ob = {
    connections: Object.assign({}, connections)
}
console.log(ob)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría algo como esto:

```
final_object = {"collections": {}};
initial_object = final_object.forEach(function(element, index) {
  final_object["collections"][index] = element
});
```

Donde initial_object es el objecto que dices que es tu entrada. Tal vez hay soluciones más elegantes pero esta funciona